# typescript TS2769 on react-query(useMutation) hook

Tags: typescript, axios, react-query

I use react-query `useMutation` hook and pass axios call inside it but typescript is error

What i'm missing ?

If i type my axios function variable with any - all fine. What type i need to assign to `LoginRequest` to fix this error?

intrefaces:

```
interface Login{
    username: string,
    password: string,

}

interface Token{
    data:{
      access_token: string,
      refresh_token: string
    }

}
```

LoginRequest function:

```
  const LoginRequest = (username: string, password: string)=> axios.post(url,
      {username: username, password: password}
   )
```

useMutation hook:

```
  const loginToServer = useMutation<Token, unknown, Login>(LoginRequest, // TS2769 No overload matches this call. (If type LoginRequest as any all works)
    { 
      onSuccess: (newLogin) => {
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', newLogin.data.access_token)
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', newLogin.data.refresh_token)
        navigate('/main')

      },

      onError: (newLogin) => {
        console.log('onError', newLogin);
      },
    },
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to type data the same type as type of  useMutation argument has

```
  const LoginRequest = (data: Login)=> axios.post(url,data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutations can only take one argument. If you have a function that takes multiple arguments, you need to either wrap it in an object, or split it up:

```
const LoginRequest = (params: Login)=> axios.post(url, params)

useMutation(LoginRequest)
```

or:

```
const LoginRequest = (username: string, password: string)=> axios.post(url,
    {username: username, password: password}
)

useMutation((login: Login) => LoginRequest(login.username, login.password))
```